# перевод UInt64 числа из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную

Tags: c#

Есть, к примеру,

```
randomInt = 5054385757817110541;
byte[] buf = BitConverter.GetBytes(randomInt);
string binTmp = string.Empty;
foreach (byte b in buf)
  binTmp += Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8,'0');
```

Переменная `randmonInt` типа `UInt64`.
По идее, в `binTmp` должна быть строка следующего вида

> 100011000100100110010010001000101000100011110111000000000001101

Однако в этой переменной содержится следующее значение:

> 0000110110000000011110110100010000010001110010010010010001000110

Помогите разобраться, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Почему так сложно? Просто вызовите эту перегрузку: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wse73s4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @АндрейNOP, там signed Int64, мне же нужен unsigned int 64 + всё-таки хотелось бы понять, в чём у меня ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже в комментариях сказали, есть перегрузка с которой можно перевести Int64 сразу в двоичную.

```
UInt64 randomInt = 5054385757817110541;
string bit = Convert.ToString((long)randomInt, 2);
```

Что касается конкретно вашей проблемы, то тут ответ прост: [Endian](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). Дело в том, что BitConverter конвертирует входной объект в соответствии с порядком байт процессора, а у x86 little endian. То есть при конвертации вы получаете по сути перевёрнутый массив, поэтому достаточно будет просто развернуть его.

```
UInt64 randomInt = 5054385757817110541;
byte[] buf = BitConverter.GetBytes(randomInt);
buf = buf.Reverse().ToArray();
string binTmp = string.Empty;
foreach (byte b in buf)
   binTmp += Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Comment: Для конвертации порядка байт можно использовать [IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.ipaddress.hosttonetworkorder(v=vs.110).aspx)